# Dataframes - equivalent to JOIN with LIKE condition, or value in sublist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes from 2 different sources.

**System A**

| system_a_id | designation |
| --- | --- |
| A10001 | Catalog A1234 |
| A10002 | Catalog A1235 |

**System B**

| system_b_id | name | other_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B20008 | Thing_B20008 | Yabbadabbadoo, Bender, Catalog A1234 |
| B20009 | Thing_B20009 | Snark Snark, Catalog A1235, Leela |

I would like to be able to join these together, into one row with all columns, based on 'designation' being found as a substring within 'other_ids'

In SQL this would be written simply as:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
  ON B.other_ids LIKE CONCAT('%', A.designation, '%')
```

Now, I imagine that there is either substring 'contains' search to use here, or I could break B.other_ids into its own list and try to do a apply function of some kind - but I'm struggling on syntax for either method, yet alone performance. (This is going to be a LOT of records joined - half a million)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "designation" appears after comma in "other_ids". You could split "other_ids" on comma, take the second parts and `assign` it as "designation" column to `systemB`. Then merge it with `systemA` on "designation":

```
out = systemB.assign(designation=systemB['other_ids'].str.split(', ').str[-1]).merge(systemA, on='designation', how='left')
```

In general, you could use `str.contains` to identify the indices that match, rearrange then `join`:

```
idx = A['designation'].apply(lambda x: B.index[B['other_ids'].str.contains(x)][0])
out = B.loc[idx].join(A)
```

Output:

```
  system_b_id          name                             other_ids  \
0      B20008  Thing_B20008  Yabbadabbadoo, Bender, Catalog A1234   
1      B20009  Thing_B20009     Snark Snark, Leela, Catalog A1235   

     designation system_a_id  
0  Catalog A1234      A10001  
1  Catalog A1235      A10002
```

Comment: Ah, I should have been more robust in my example, it could show up anywhere in "other_ids" list

Comment: Thanks! First approach only works when 'designation' is found as the 2nd entry in the list, and the second approach is having an IndexError. I'll keep poking

Comment: @iontom I messed up the order of A and B. see if the update works